# Webhook architecture for managing millions of subscribers (who are customers)

Tags: azure, events, architecture, webhooks, publish-subscribe

My Azure based SaaS system publishes events and I have customers who wish to subscribe to them - webhooks seem undeniably the right architecture (And I'm currently a happy consumer of webhooks). I've found lots of great documentation and case studies on best practices (e.g. http://resthooks.org) however I've not managed to find an existing architecture, framework, project, sample or solution that implements the best practices.

I could build my own solution however I don't want to reinvent the wheel.  I was expecting to find an existing framework (e.g. on Github) created by people much smarter than I but haven't had any success.

I currently use a number of Azure services (such as Service Bus, Cosmos, Table Storage) internally and consume using Azure Functions but what I don't have is an architecture for allowing my customers to subscribe to these events.

**Specifically I'm looking for best practices and code samples on how to manage potentially millions of subscribers (who are external customers) and the approach to distribute the webhooks out to each of them.**

I already understand how to publish and consume webhooks where I am an individual subscriber and there are already some great samples available - https://github.com/aspnet/AspLabs/tree/master/src/WebHooks

Can anyone point me in the right direction? (Preferably to a .NET / C# based solution)

Comment: Have you looked at using custom events in event grid?

Comment: Event Grid definitely looks like an excellent foundation to build upon and it ties in nicely with my Azure based solution (oh how I love Azure - just had to throw that in).  From what I can see it will require some customisation in order to connect subscriptions to my specific customers but definitely more sane than building from scratch.  I'll do some more research and get a handle on the level of effort required between what Event Grid provides and my (largely conceptual at this stage) requirements.

Comment: @Fanetic - Did you ever land on a solution to your problem?  Did you go the custom route?

Comment: @StephenMcDowell - no, never ended up with implementing the webhooks. The solution we are using allows the 'requester' to provide a 'callback' endpoint to which we post the events. It meets my needs for the moment however I eventually need a solution to this issue.  Solving it has moved down my priority list however still interested if anyone else has.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the 'right' direction but here are my current thoughts on a solution.

We are currently using CosmosDb and are leveraging the change feed to trigger an Azure function execution.  The code within the function does a specific task for all tenants in our system.  This code will be changed to simply send a new event to the Event Grid topic.  A 'in-house' subscription will then be added that will handle what the function code is currently doing today.

We will then follow the [subscription management guidance](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/reference/#rest-hooks) Zapier offers.  In a nutshell it is to expose the capability to our customers to subscribe to the events that we publish via a few endpoints. In addition to standard CRUD stuff when a tenant adds/removes a subscription the code will leverage the Event Grid Management SDK to add/remove subscriptions to the appropriate topics within Event Grid ([samples here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/event-grid-dotnet-publish-consume-events/event-grid-dotnet-publish-consume-events/)).  The subscriptions that get added will have filters set to ensure each tenant only receives their own events.

There are limitations to the number of subscriptions and topics with in Azure ([details here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/event-grid/)).  These limitations are acceptable in our case but is something you might need to look into more if you need to reach 1mm subscribers.

Here is how I visualize it:
[image]

Not 100% we'll build this but if we do I'll post back here any gotchas we uncover.

Cheers!